# Sorting/Ordering string array in rtfbox and text file

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array defined in another class that gets its values from textBoxes that I append to an rtfbox, and I can save this rtfBox to a text file in this format:

1. firstname, lastname, 02/03/4567, 89
2. John, Smith, 01/02/1995, 100
3. aa, bb, 01/02/1995, 88
4. cc, dd, 08/09/7777, 22

I append this string array to the rtfbox using:

```
return (Convert.ToString(studentID) + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " +
        dob + ", " + Convert.ToString(averageMark));

bc[0] = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, dob, averageMark);

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    string bcString = bc[i].bankCustomerToString() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.AppendText(bcString);
}
```

Is there a way I could order the text file or active `rtfbox` by `averageMark` and then by `dateofbirth` with a button?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? It appears that you are creating an array of type `Student` with the values entered into the text box, so you could potentially use LINQ to sort the array how you need to and then serialize it back out (as per your current code)

Comment: What type are the variables in `Student`? i.e. are they `string`, `double`, etc.

Comment: Please update your code. Currently is difficult to see what is happening. You order your text file by loading it in memory in an collection of Student objects, then sorting that collection using LINQ, and than storing sorted collection back into file. The same goes with string content of rich text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var ordered = students.OrderBy(s => s.averageMark).ThenBy(s => s.dob);
foreach(var student in ordered)
    // richTextBox1.Append(.....);
```

If you want to order descending, use `OrderByDescending` and/or `ThenByDescending`.